# Click on first item autocomplete jQuery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to click on the first item of the list that displays autocomplete after searching:

```
$(function(){
    $('#autocompleteplace').each(function(i, el) {
        var $this = $(el);
        $this.autocomplete({
            source: $this.data('urlp'),
            autoFocus: true,
            minLength: 1,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#' + $this.data('id')).val(ui.item.id);
            }
        });
        var region = '{{ form.vars.data.place.region|default('') }}';
        $this.autocomplete("search", region, true);
        var menu = $this.autocomplete("widget");

        $(menu[0].children[0]).click();
    });
});
```

This code is the same from [here](https://uiadventures.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/default-selection-jquery-autocomplete/), which I tried in the same environment and it works. But in my example I get the data from the server, and it shows and selects the first item with autoFocus, but it doesn't click on it.

I just want to edit a post that uses a field with autocomplete (place), so when the form is shown I want it to have the place already selected.

Comment: Have you tried `$(menu[0].children[0]).trigger("click");` ?

Comment: I have now, but I get the same: it shows the region autofocused but it doesn't click on it :(

Comment: Ok, what is the purpose of taking the click action away from the user? If this is the case, why not close the autocomplete and set the value of the text field?

Comment: The purpose is to get the value of the id of the region when submit. I have set the attribute "value" with the value of the region too, but it doesn't grab the id, if I submit the form it's like If I didn't write anything, because it doesn't send any request

Comment: Need to see the form code to see what's happening.

Comment: Well it's made with Symfony Form component, but that part works: it retrieves the values correctly when I type something. I created 2 fiddles: one with the working simple code https://jsfiddle.net/m15o344p/ and this one with the part of my form https://jsfiddle.net/Lmxxjaab/. I have both code samples in the same html and the simple one works but not the other. I see now that the request is sent, but still the input doesn't take the value, a click on the item of the list is needed

Comment: Need an example of the `source` in your 2nd fiddle. What is: `data-urlp="{{ path(form.place.vars.update_route) }}"`

Comment: With a proper source, this appears to work: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/m15o344p/2/

Comment: That is a Twig path that links to the source of the data. It retrieves the places when you start typing. As I said, that part works, the item I'm looking for (place) is retrieved correctly, and it's also marked as focused. The thing that does not work is the last step, when it has to be selected. Your fiddle does not select one item by default, it does not do like in here https://jsfiddle.net/m15o344p/ (Thank you for your help though)

Comment: I am aware that it is substituted with content, I need to know what an example of that content would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked for a quick fix of that problem: retrieve the value of the item that its already stored, but it's easier and cleaner doing it in the form. My fix was modify the Transformer in my Symfony form. Since this is not a PHP topic, I'm not going into details.

**In conclusion: there should be a better way to achieve that than forcing a click() event.**